# angularjs 7 Access-Control-Allow-Origin blocked by cors policy

Tags: angular, rest, api

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 

http://badamirchi.com/wldev/api/Services//SignIn 
from origin 
http://localhost:4200 has been blocked by CORS policy:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Below is the issue I am getting.

[image: below issue am getting]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like eithr you need to set more appropriate CORS headers or the resource you are trying to access doesnt allow localhost domain access.
Do you have an API key setup with this service? You may need to add localhost into your approved domains (Google AUTH requires this)

Comment: how to add cors header in angularr?