# Cross origin request block

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, angular7

I am working on angular fronted project and using angular7 project.
I am using aws api as backend. Whenever I call the aws api its giving me
 following errors.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/XXX/subscriptionpayment. (Reason: missing token ‘access-control-allow-origin’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel).

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/XXX/subscriptionpayment. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

I am using following code

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
  })
};

     let makePaymentUrl = "https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxxx/subscriptionpayment";
return this.http.post(makePaymentUrl, params,httpOptions);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable CORS in the API gateway end point. 
Follow : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html#how-to-cors-console

Comment: Yes CORS is enable already at API gateway end point but still have the issue

Comment: when I hit the same Api using postman its working as expected, but when I call it from angular application then its giving me CORS issue

Comment: This issue has been resolved by removing headers from request.


     let makePaymentUrl = "https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxxx/subscriptionpayment";
return this.http.post(makePaymentUrl, params);

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling this request? if its a localhost maybe aws doesnt allow access to it. Check your API keys for this services

or double check your headers 
try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53454800/angularjs-7-access-control-allow-origin-blocked-by-cors-policy?rq=1)

Comment: I am  calling the request from localhost and live server as well but same errors is  occurs.
AS per my comment I have adding 'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*' header to my request